# Importing module in JS script inside HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, import

Why does line 3 break this example? It works fine with line 3 commented out.

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<script type="module">
  import { foo } from "script.js";    // BREAKS THINGS

  document.getElementById("button")
    .addEventListener("click",
      function(){ alert("hello") } );
</script>
```

Tested in MS Edge 93.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It just doesn't give any feedback when I test in browser

Comment: You have the console open?

Comment: Oh I can't believe I didn't know about seeing errors on the console, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly, `"script.js"` should be `"./script.js"`. After that, the console shows an error

```
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/jordanb/Dropbox/Git/test/script.js' from
origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https,
chrome-untrusted.
```

The fix is to use a server as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912641/access-to-script-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-error-whil).

Comment: There's no difference between `script.js and `./script.js`

Comment: You'd think so, but the `"script.js"` gave me a "file not found" error.

Comment: he's right using or omitting the `./` doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

It breaks your code, since `script.js` doesn't exist. In order to be able to import the module you have to add it before using

Comment: How do you know that the file doesn't exist?