# Proper way to import functions from other file in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have few functions in functions.ts file, like this:

```
function fun1(input: string): boolean {
{...}
}
```

and in the end of file, I export these functions:

```
export {fun1, fun2, fun3};
```

In the index.ts file, that is called in html (it's very simple client-side app), I import these functions:

```
import {isInputValid, receiveExchangeValueFromAPI, convertCurrency} from "./functions";
```

When I run it in the browser (of course after `npx tsc` ) I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, pointing on the import statement in index.js file

I tried to change few lines inside package.json and tsconfig.json, according to the answers in similar questions.

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsdom": "^21.1.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "es2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

I tried many configurations of "target", "module" and "type" options in both files, but I get errors, sometimes slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link your script, make sure to have `type="module"`:

```html
<script type="module" src="./path/to/my/transpiled/javascript.js"></script>
```

Reference: [JavaScript Modules: Applying the module to your HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)

Comment: Ok, looks like I have to put type="module" on both files in html. And I need some local server (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912641/access-to-script-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-error-whil). But I will probably manage that. Thanks